# How to make a top-down menu in Jade

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am using `Bootstrap` for this implementation. So I followed the guidelines in creating a drop-down menu from the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns/) . This drop-down menu should contain a room list. The menu is called 'Rooms'.  My `Jade` and `Javascript` files are below (just the implementation of the drop-down menu).

editor.jade

```
extends layout

block header
script(src='/javascripts/editor.js')

block content
h1(id="title") Editor

h2 Editor: #{editorName}
.dropdown
 button#dropdownMenu1.btn.dropdown-toggle.sr-only(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown')
  | Rooms
  span.caret
 ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu', aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu1')
  #rooms
...
```

editor.js(javascript)

```
...
$.getJSON("/getContents", {theRoom: "roomList"},  function(room) {

   room.activeRooms.forEach(function(theExit){

       $('#rooms').replaceWith('<li  id="rooms" role="presentation">' + theExit+'</li>')
   });
});
...
```

Unfortunately, there is no top-down menu displayed on the screen. Can you please look at my code and tell me what I did wrong?

P.S. If my question is not clear, can you please tell me so that I can elaborate?

Comment: Please put your example into this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timaschew/34BMe/3/ you need to add the bootstrap files, too (as external resources for instance)